# Url Rewriting for Static Files

Tags: php

I want url rewriting . I am making a script and to seperate other static page like register.php , login .php from the root folder i put it on a sub folder named root_files

So the login.php and other static files are located in mydomain.com/root_files/login.php and I don't want that public see the folder. So i made coding that slightly hide the url

This coding is in other file that is including in index.php file of website

```
if(isset($_GET["page"]) && $_GET["page"]=='login')
{
 include'root_files/login.php';
 die();
}
```

So when someone open mydomain.com/index.php?page=login it show the file that is present in mydomain.com/root_files/login.php

And I don't know for .htaccess coding.

So I want coding that rewrite url when i open mydomain.com/login it show the file that is present in mydomain.com/root_files/login.php and so on for other static pages like register etc etc.

Comment: Hello I got this one code It is working But when I use mydomain.com/root_files it is rewriting it also to mydomain.com/root_files/?page=root_files

    `RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Hehe I got the code for my solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum$
```